# Xlsxwriter Replacing text when applying background fill to range

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I'm applying a background fill in a range using xlsxwriter and while doing this, it is replacing the text written on that particular range.
**please don't suggest to use conditional formatting.**

**This is what I'm doing:**

```
for row in range(8,9):
    for col in range(2,13):
        cell_reference = xl_rowcol_to_cell (row, col, row_abs=True, col_abs=True)
        worksheet.write ('{}'.format (cell_reference), None, format_header)
```

**so the input is:**
[image]

**expected output:**
[image]

**code output:**
[image]

See its replacing the headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm applying a background fill in a range using xlsxwriter and while doing this, it is replacing the text written on that particular range.

That is the way XlsxWriter works. You will need to write the format with the data. You can't do it separately.

Also, side note, you don't need to create a cell reference to pass to `write()` it can take numeric `(row, col)` instead. See the [Working with Cell Notation](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_cell_notation.html#cell-notation) section of the docs.